# Dynamodb item designed for retrieval

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-design, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

We are making an internal collector for the meta data around deploying kube images to clusters and storing in dynamodb (it would keep track of every time a new image tag is deployed in a list). This will be the first time I am working with dynamodb and maybe the 5th time with nosql concepts.

Thinking about rest calls they would like: to get all items by service_name, cluster_name, and image_name. Initially, I did not understand how differently the retrieval work in this database vs relational. I now understand I will be using an anti pattern as I do not plan on using the UUID for any useful searching and would need to make 3 Global Search Indexes that would allow me to make those other retrievals.....is this really the best way to do it?

I feel like I may be missing the mark.

The only other thing I could think of is to see if the users of the system would be fine with always giving me the cluster_name and service_name as a base. Then I could make that a concatenated field and search based on that.

Data I would like to store:

```
{ "uuid" : "generated_uui",
  "cluster_name" : "cluster",
  "service_name" : "servicename",
  "image_name" : "imagename",
  "image_tags" : [{"date" : "date", "tag" : "imagetag"},
                  {"date" : "date", "tag" : "imagetag"}
                 ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your problem creating a GSI for every attribute you want it to be queryable? For now,  you have three service_name, cluster_name, and image_name.

If thats the case you can do [GSI Overloading](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-gsi-overloading.html), and make use of schemaless advantages of DynamoDB. In short, you can put your queryable attributes in a single attribute (which will be your sort key and also your GSI partition key)

Example 1:

```
|   PartitionKey  | SortKey and GSI PartionKey |  Atrribute 1 | Atrribute 2 | 
|:---------------:|---------------------------:|:------------:|
| generated_uui_1 |        image_tags          |     [{tag: 1}]     
| generated_uui_1 | cluster:a_cluster_name_1   |         
| generated_uui_1 | service:a_service_name_1   |     
| generated_uui_1 | image:a_image_name_1       |        
| generated_uui_2 |        image_tags          |     [{tag: 2}]     
| generated_uui_2 | cluster:a_cluster_name_2   |       
| generated_uui_2 | service:a_service_name_2   |     
| generated_uui_2 | image:a_image_name_2       |
```

Here you can query both 3 attributes in single GSI. But it has to be the exact match of the string you are searching for because its only hash key.

If you want to query for instance clusters with starting 'a_cluster' prefix you can simply modify the upper table to this

Example 2:

```
|   PartitionKey  | SortKey and GSI PartionKey |  Atrribute 1 (GSI SortKey) | Atrribute 2 | 
|:---------------:|---------------------------:|:--------------------------:|
| generated_uui_1 |        image_tags          |     [{tag: 1}]     
| generated_uui_1 |        cluster_name        |     a_cluster_name_1  
| generated_uui_1 |        service_name        |     a_service_name_1
| generated_uui_1 |        image_name          |     a_image_name_1   
| generated_uui_2 |        image_tags          |     [{tag: 2}]     
| generated_uui_2 |        cluster_name        |     a_cluster_name_2  
| generated_uui_2 |        service_name        |     a_service_name_2
| generated_uui_2 |        image_name          |     a_image_name_2
```

Now with the advantages of the Sort Key you can query with for instance `BEGINS_WITH` (and many more capabilities), such as `Get me all services that starts with 'a_service_name'`

But now it requires extra read if you want to get image_tags of 'a_service_name_1` item. Or you can denormalize it Attribute 1, Attribute 2 so on...

Comment: Make a lot more sense why you are limited to 5 GSIs. Thanks CanSahin,